# RxJava2 delay doesn't work

Tags: android, rx-java2

I have Repository method:

```
public Maybe<String> getId(String id){
    return mApiInterface.get().getId(id)
            .subscribeOn(mSchedulerProvider.io())
            .observeOn(mSchedulerProvider.mainThread());
}
```

I am trying to use this method in cycle with delay:

```
 final ArrayList<String> ids = SharedPreferenceProvider.getIds();

    for(final String id:ids) {
        mRepository.get().getId(id)
                .delay(5, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
                .subscribeWith(new DisposableMaybeObserver<String>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onSuccess(String s) {  }

                    @Override
                    public void onError(Throwable e) { }

                    @Override
                    public void onComplete() {  }
                });
    }
```

But the delay method doesn't work. What am I doing wrong? Sometimes I need a delay between two requests.

**Final variant of the decision:**

```
Flowable.zip(Flowable.fromIterable(ids),
                        Flowable.interval(0, 5, TimeUnit.SECONDS).onBackpressureBuffer(),
                        new BiFunction<String, Long, String>() {
                            @Override
                            public String apply(String s, Long aLong) throws Exception {
                                return s;
                            }
                        }
                ).flatMapMaybe(new Function<String, MaybeSource<String>>() {
                    @Override
                    public MaybeSource<String> apply(String s) throws Exception {
                        return mRepository.get().testMaybe(s);
                    }
                }).subscribeWith(new DisposableSubscriber<String>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onNext(String s) {

                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onError(Throwable t) {

                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onComplete() {

                    }
                });
```

Comment: you can try with debounce operator instaed of delay. e.g  .debounce(TIME_REQUIRED, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS)

Comment: There isn't debounce and interval operators in RxJava2

Comment: There are but not with Maybe. Flowable and Observable have those

Comment: How does it "not work"? What is your expected behavior?

Comment: I need to send request with id every 5 seconds.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I need to send request with id every 5 seconds.
>
> But I need - mRepository.get().getId(id1) - wait 5 sec - mRepository.get().getId(id2) - wait 5 sec - etc

You could zip with an interval, then flatMap in the repository call

```
Flowable.fromArray(ids) // or fromIterable(ids)
.zipWith(
    Flowable.interval(0, 5, TimeUnit.SECONDS).onBackpressureBuffer(),
    (id, time) -> id
)
.flatMapMaybe(id -> mRepository.get().getId(id), 1)
// .repeat()
.subscribe(/* ... */)
```

Comment: Akarnokd, thank you. But it's wrong. This method wait 5 seconds and then send all requests simultaneously. After that repeate this from 5 seconds. But I need - mRepository.get().getId(id1) - wait 5 sec - mRepository.get().getId(id2) - wait 5 sec - etc

Comment: Updated the answer.

Comment: Can you show all code in flatMapMaybe operator? (without lambda)

Comment: Does the Interval operator stop?

Comment: What's wrong with the lambda form? Any modern IDE can transform it into anyonymous inner class representation. Ids is finite so `zipWith` will stop once it runs out of those ids.

Comment: In flatMapMaybe we get ArrayList (ids), not String (id). And we can't use the request.

Comment: What is the type of your `ids`? Have you properly copied the example or did you modify it in some ways, (such as `just(ids)`?).

Comment: ArrayList, i added it to code. But I spoke about your scheme. In flatMap we get all items, not one item.

Comment: You need to change -  Flowable.zip(Flowable.fromIterable(ids), Flowable.interval...  and all will be work. Thank you for your code.

Answer (score 0):

Try it!

```
public Maybe<String> getId(String id){
    return mApiInterface.get().getId(id)
            .delay(5, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
            .subscribeOn(mSchedulerProvider.io());
}
```

//And

```
 for(final String id:ids) {
               mRepository.get().getId(id)
                       .observeOn(mSchedulerProvider.mainThread())
                       .subscribeWith(new DisposableMaybeObserver<String>() 
{
                   @Override
                   public void onSuccess(String s) {  }

                   @Override
                   public void onError(Throwable e) { }

                   @Override
                   public void onComplete() {  }
               });
   }
```